# RangeError [ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE]: File size (9509257216) is greater than 2 GB

Tags: reactjs, file, memory-management, build, upload-max-filesize

ERROR in ./src/images/services/devops-2.svg
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@svgr/webpack/lib/index.js):
RangeError [ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE]: File size (9509257216) is greater than 2 GB
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterStat [as oncomplete] (node:fs:335:11)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to change max-file-size limit